# How to concat string in a column in oracle sql using update statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to concat a string in a column in oracle SQL

```
Name     Info
A        Age=10,Section='A'
B        Age=9,Section='B'
Demo
```

I want to add string fee(int) in column Info(varchar2(100)) of table Demo as below output using update statements  :

```
Name     Info    
A        Age=10,Section='A',fee=1000
B        Age=9,Section='B',fee=2000

Demo
```

Comment: Is this for reporting only, or do you want to store the data in that format, in a table in your database? If it's for reporting only, fine; but if you are thinking of storing the data in the database in that format, which seems to be the case as you mentioned `update`, that is a horrible idea. Read about **First Normal Form** to understand why.

Comment: What is the logic to calculate the fee?

Answer (score 0):

The string concatenation operator is `||`.  You would do something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (info || (case when name = 'A' then ',fee=1000'
                      when name = 'B' then ',fee=2000'
                 end)
       ) as new_info
from t;
```

This logic could also be incorporated into an `update`:

```
update t
    set info = (info || (case when name = 'A' then ',fee=1000'
                              when name = 'B' then ',fee=2000'
                         end)
               ) 
    where name in ('A', 'B');
```